# error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte in Socket Programming

Tags: python, sockets

Hello so I've been doing a Python Socket Programming. What I want to do is send a string variable called "option" to server.

This is the Client code

```
option = "4"
client.send(option.encode())
```

I got the 'error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte'.

So here is my server code.

```
option = client.recv(512).decode()
```

The option in server should received a String that has a value as "4" but like I said I got an error.
Could anyone know how to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might try being explicit with your `encode` and `decode` calls by adding a `'utf-8'` parameter.  Then check `len(option)` after the `recv`.

Comment: I've tried adding `utf-8` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @oatty8867 - did you add explicit encoding in both the client and the server?

Comment: `0xff` is the start of the BOM for Microsoft's UTF-16 (and sometimes UTF-8) encoding. You can call `locale.getpreferredencoding()` in both the client and the server to see what they are currently using.

Comment: How to do it. I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since network programming tyically envolves multiple machines that can have different encodings, one should define the encoding for a protocol. It can either be a single encoding everyone must use (a very good choice these days) or there needs to be a way to negotiate the encoding in the protocol itself.

In your case you could just hard code it:

```
option = "4"
client.send(option.encode(encoding="utf-8"))
```

and

```
option = client.recv(512).decode(encoding="utf-8")
```

This still has a glaring bug. recv doesn't receive things in the exact size of the sender. If your encoded characters is, say, 3 bytes, the receiver may receive a partial character. That means you need some way of demarking strings so that both sides know where a given character or string ends. But that's a different kettle of fish.

There are many existing protocols out there to deal with message boundaries, encoding, and etc. HTTP, XMLRPC, Zeromq are just a few. These can be a lot easier than rolling your own solution.

Comment: I hard code it as you suggested but it's still got an error 
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 34: invalid start byte`
@tdelaney

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Instead of decoding, can you try `print(client.recv(512))` so that we can see the full set of octets being decoded? Also, on the machine that does the send, what is `print("4".encode("utf-8"))`? They should match.

Comment: I printed the `print(client.recv(512))` so it print the really really long encoded string so I printed the `print("4".encode("utf-8"))` to check what it should be to encoded "4" and it's just a b'4'.

Comment: So, you weren't just receiving the "4". What is the start of that long bytes object... say the first 16 bytes? The bit of code you've shown is only the "4"... if you receive much more, then there is a different part of your code sending that extra stuff. You are likely getting a Byte Order Mark (BOM), see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for the various BOMS. They are commonly used on microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out ! so I changed from this

```
option = client.recv(512).decode()
```

to this

```
option = client.recv(1).decode()
```

and it's worked ! so my conclusion is Client trying to send a String to server.
What I want to send to server is "4" so the size of block that Client try to send is 1.

I'm not sure but this worked for me.